# Scale just div,not what's inside it

Tags: html, css

as you see in the code I have a div and one image in it.I want to scale div without changing the image size.How do I do that?
http://jsfiddle.net/8n96x8wx/22/

CODE:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-origin: top;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.parent:hover {
  transform: scaleY(2.0);
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px black solid
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1347/6161/products/dankMemes-2_819e8d98-5746-47bd-90fd-063fae1c7d06_1024x1024_crop_bottom.progressive.jpg?v=1497447755">
</div>
```

Comment: _"How do I do that?"_ - you can't, a transformation isn't something you can "turn off" for descendant elements - at most you can _reverse_ it, by applying the opposite transformation to the image.

Answer (score 1):

In such case I would rather suggest you to use the `transition` property together with the doubled `height`:

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-origin: top;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.parent:hover {
  transition: height;
  height: 400px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px black solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1347/6161/products/dankMemes-2_819e8d98-5746-47bd-90fd-063fae1c7d06_1024x1024_crop_bottom.progressive.jpg?v=1497447755">
</div>
```

Comment: Thats a good way,but in my case i have to do it with transform:scale :c

Answer (score 0):

Just add the opposing transform to parent's child:

```css
    .parent {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      transform-origin: 0% 0;
      margin: 50px;
      border: 1px black solid;
    }

    .parent:hover {
      transform: scaleY(2.0);
    }
    
    .parent:hover img {
      transform: scaleY(0.5);
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px black solid
    }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1347/6161/products/dankMemes-2_819e8d98-5746-47bd-90fd-063fae1c7d06_1024x1024_crop_bottom.progressive.jpg?v=1497447755">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first don't scale the container div scale the image , sconde why use `scaleY`
when you want to zoom the image see this :

Plus always add some `transition` to create an zooming effect

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-origin: top;
  margin: 50px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.parent:hover img{
  transform: scale(2.0);
  transition:all 1s ease-out;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px black solid;
  transition:all 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1347/6161/products/dankMemes-2_819e8d98-5746-47bd-90fd-063fae1c7d06_1024x1024_crop_bottom.progressive.jpg?v=1497447755">
</div>
```